# Are Cycles particles less voluminous than Eevee particles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles, eevee-render-engine

Does Cycles produce particles different from Eevee?

| [image: Cycles] | [image: Eevee] |
| --- | --- |
| In Cycles | In Eevee |

Unfortunately, the size of my .blend file is too large to upload to https://pasteall.org for posting the file.

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.com/ to upload file

Answer (score 1):

I learned that inside the Particle System, changing the Children from 'None' to 'Interpolated' will add more hair.
If more thickness is wanted, in Hair Shape, the hair root and/or tip can be thickened, producing a similar effect.